# Insert data into SQL Server from C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table `student` (`id, name`). Then I have one textbox, for entering the name, when click on submit button, it inserts the data into the database. So how can I insert only to name, not id because id is auto increment?

I tried this

```
insert into student(id, name) values(,name)
```

but it is not insert to my table.

This is my code :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string test = txtName.Text;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Person.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

    string sql = "insert into student(name) values ('test')";

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
    {
        string msg = "Insert Error:";
        msg += ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried insert into student(name) values(name)

Comment: Not only that, it gave you a syntax error, probably near `,`.  If you have code which generates errors, it's normally a good idea to include those error details in full.

Comment: If your question is answered, mark it as answered

Comment: In the Asp.Net is the same kind of code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO student (name) values ('name')
```

Omit the `id` column altogether, it will be populated automatically. To use your variable, you should parameterise your SQL query.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO student (name) values (@name)";
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = test;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You should never attempt to do this by constructing a SQL string containing the input value, as this can expose your code to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: titi Provide more code (the whole shebang that includes the insert and database communications) and we might help you, the SQL statement in itself IS correct as David M displays it.

Comment: Is the row not inserted at all, or is it inserted with the value "test" rather than the contents of your text box? Have updated my answer with code to solve the latter...

Answer (score 2):

You better use parameters when you insert data.

```
try
{
    string sql = "insert into student(name) values (@name)";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", test); // assign value to parameter 
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    string msg = "Insert Error:";
    msg += ex.Message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mention the ID in first part.

```
insert into student(name) values('name')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO student (name) values (@name)";
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = test;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem and after trying various solution found at stack overflow, i could summarize the experience as follows:
commands executed in command shell of mssql like:

`insert into table_name (val1,val2,val3,val4) VALUES ("val1","val2",0,"val4")`

`go`

or

`insert into table_name VALUES ("val1","val2",0,"val4")`

```
go
```

work when typed directly in the mssql database prompt,

But when it is required to use the the insert statement from c#, it is required to be kept in mind that string needs to be surrounded by an additional pair of single quites, around the strings, like in:

```
SqlConnection cnn;

string connetionString = "Data Source=server_name;Initial Catalog=database_name;User ID=User_ID;Password=Pass_word";

cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into table_name (val1,val2,val3,val4) VALUES ('val1','val2',0,'val4');", cnn);

//or
//SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insert into table_name VALUES ('val1','val2',0,'val4');", cnn);

cnn.Open();

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

cnn.Close();
```

the problem here is that most people, like myself, try to use <\"> in the place of double quotes <">that is implemented as in the above command line case, and SQL executor fails to understand the meaning of this.

Even in cases where a string needs to be replace, ensure that strings are surrounded by **single quotation**, where a string concatination looks like a feasible solution, like in:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into table_name (val1,val2,val3,val4) VALUES ('"+val1+"','val2',0,'val4');", cnn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query,

```
insert into student(name) values(name)
```

SQL Server internally auto increments the id column when u insert the data since u said it is auto increment.  If it is not working, the u have to check the identity column in the db.

Answer (score 0):

use the key word "identity" to auto increment the id column

Refer : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(v=sql.80).aspx

```
create table table_name( id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY )
```

and you no need to mention the "id"  in the insert query