# c# program inserting rows in sql database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, database

I know I have done this a few times before but for the life of me can't remember how.
I have a database I have created and I want to make a software that only inputs information into the database. The program works but my sql connection is the problem. So to test it out I basically tried to do it direct inserting hard-coded info but it still will not go. where am I going wrong?:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.Common;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data.Sql;

    namespace InventoryTracker
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
          public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }


            public static void CreateCommand()
            {
                SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("User Id=Jab" + "password=''" + "Data Source=localhost;" + "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + "database=InventoryTracker;" + "Table=Inventory;");

                try
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Inventory (ItemName, SerialNumber, Model, Department, Quantity, Notes) " + "Values (string,string,string,string, 1, string)", myConnection);

            }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance! :-)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Where do you execute the query?

Comment: You don't need to use `+` in your connection string. And, nobody can know right connection string except you.

Comment: Here is a sample to go http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

Comment: I don't think you need username and password in the connection string if you say it's a trusted connection... trusted connection is telling SQL to use windows authentication. Username and password tells it to use SQL authentication.

Comment: also there is no `;` between your userID and password and password to dataSource

Answer (score 3):

Your sql connection string is messed up, you need semi-colons between all parameters and your parameters are messed up too. I.e., something like

"Server=localhost;Database=InventoryTracker;Trusted_Connection=True;"

You are mixing trusted mode and specifying the user id -- trusted connection means to use your windows login credentials.

TableName does not go in the connection string.

This site is great for connection string examples http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

You SQL command, "INSERT INTO Inventory (ItemName ..." is pretty messed up too. Should be something like

INSERT INTO Inventory (ItemName ...) values(@ItemName ...)

You then pass in the values like

myCommand.Parameters.Add("ItemName", SqlType.VarChar).Value = "Dozen Eggs";

See [Insert data into SQL Server from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030183/insert-data-into-sql-server-from-c-sharp-code) for a simple example

Comment: Thank you all. All replies helped

Answer (score 3):

Just use the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx

Instead of:

```
"User Id=Jab" + "password=''" + "Data Source=localhost;" + "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + "database=InventoryTracker;" + "Table=Inventory;");
```

Try:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.UserID = "Jab";
builder.Password = "";
builder.DataSource = "localhost";
builder.InitialCatalog = "InventoryTracker";
```

Comment: I've never used SqlConnectionStringBuilder. My connection strings have always been in a configuration file so that it is not compiled into the app. But a potentially useful alternative I've never notice before. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
// Don't put table name in your connection string
    string connection_str = "Data Source = localhost ; uid = db_user; pwd = db_pass; database = db_name; ";
     conn = new SqlConnection(connection_str);
     conn.Open();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
"User Id=Jab" + "password=''" + "Data Source=localhost;" + "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + "database=InventoryTracker;" + "Table=Inventory;"
```

to

```
"User Id=Jab; " + "Password=''; " + "Data Source=localhost; " + "Trusted_Connection=yes; " + "Initial Catalog=InventoryTracker;"
```

(Changed upper/lower case, "Database" to "Initial Catalog", removed "Table" and added ";")

---

Also, you might want to try replacing "Data Source" by "Server".

Comment: Data Source and Server are synonyms. Database and Initial Catalog are synonyms. Connection string is not case sensitive though password, etc. in the string are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to call `myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` to get it to actually execute your query. Without this, you are just creating a command, but not running it.