# How to connect to SQL SERVER and insert data into database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert data into SQL SERVER 2008 using C#.
When connecting, I followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17265068). When inserting data into database, used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11030203). Result is data is not inserted into database. Problem is Visual Studio is not giving any errors. What can cause this?

Here is my code:

```
DateTime Start = DateTime.Now;
        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=UrbanPlan; " +
                                   "connection timeout=30");
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            //here is giving successfull message
            Console.WriteLine("Successful");
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You failed!" + ex.Message);
        }

        string csv_file_path = @"C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\geocoding.csv";
        DataTable csvData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);

        int num = 0;
        while (num < 10)
        {
            double longitude = Convert.ToDouble(csvData.Rows[num][1]);
            double latitude = Convert.ToDouble(csvData.Rows[num][2]);

            int numForCheck = 0;
            while (longitude != Convert.ToDouble(csvData.Rows[numForCheck][1]) && latitude != Convert.ToDouble(csvData.Rows[numForCheck][2]))
            {
                numForCheck++;
            }

            if (numForCheck == num)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(longitude, latitude));
            }
            num++;
        }

        double eps = 1.0;
        int minPts = 2;
        List<List<Point>> clusters = GetClusters(points, eps, minPts);
        //Console.Clear();
        // print points to console
        Console.WriteLine("The {0} points are :\n", points.Count);
        foreach (Point p in points) Console.Write(" {0} ", p);
        Console.WriteLine();
        // print clusters to console
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < clusters.Count; i++)
        {
            int count = clusters[i].Count;
            total += count;
            string plural = (count != 1) ? "s" : "";
            Console.WriteLine("\nCluster {0} consists of the following {1} point{2} :\n", i + 1, count, plural);
            foreach (Point p in clusters[i])
            {
                string sql = "INSERT INTO AntennaLocationByRegions (RegionId, Longitude, Latitude) values (@RegionId, @Longitude, @Latitude)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RegionId", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd.Parameters["@RegionId"].Value = i + 1;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Longitude", SqlDbType.Float);
                cmd.Parameters["@Longitude"].Value = p.Long;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Latitude", SqlDbType.Float);
                cmd.Parameters["@Latitude"].Value = p.Lat;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: does the debugger stop if you set a breakpoint on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`?

Comment: Is "clusters" surely not empty (Count = 0)? Anyways: Use "Finally" or "using" to secure close your connection even if an error occurs

Comment: @Pengu, I printed with Console.WriteLine() before, there were 34 clusters.

Comment: @Pengu, I found my error. It was because of while(num < 10). I changed it into while(num < csvData.Rows.Count). Now everything fine

Comment: You can add your own fix/answer as an answer. Then after two days flag your own answer as answered. This helps the community clean from open questions which not is open. Thank's for help!

Answer (score -1):

Try this code for connection

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Database=yourdatabasename;Server=yourpcname\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;connect timeout = 60");
```

Comment: If the connection string was wrong, the .Open call would fail.