# sql statement does not work on specific table

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I Have a website which creates new order and saves shopping bag items into database.
The thing is that insert into,select,update,delete sentences are working in all my tables except one, i think i wrote the sentence perfectly but its still throw excption that says something wrong with the sentence.

```
string OrderSql = string.Format(@"
    INSERT INTO Order ([UserID],[DayMonthYear],[PriceToPay],[StatusID],[AdressToSend]) 
    VALUES ({0},{1},{2},{3},'{4}')",
 UserId, DateTime.Now, Price, 1, Address);
```

at first i thought the problem may be found at the db so i copied my db into new once still doesnt working 
i would send the relationship between tables but i need 10 rep..

Comment: `order` is a reserved word. Escape it like this `[order]`

Comment: Look at this posting and how to use Parameters this will help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030183/insert-data-into-sql-server-from-c-sharp-code

Comment: Try to avoid naming tables and columns with reserved words.  A table called select or from or where (or 'or' for that matter) will hit the same error.  If it's not too late, rename that table.  If it is too late, use Juergen's suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two issues. Firstly as @juergen points out in the comments `order` is a reserved word so you'll need to enclose it in square brackets. Secondly, you don't have the date enclosed in quotes. So your code should read:

```
string OrderSql = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO [Order] ([UserID],[DayMonthYear],[PriceToPay],[StatusID],[AdressToSend]) 
VALUES ({0},'{1}',{2},{3},'{4}')", UserId, DateTime.Now, Price, 1, Address);
```

Note the square brackets around `Order` and the single quotes around `{1}`.

**However**, you are open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks using that code so I would strongly suggest you read up on using parameterized queries. @DJ KRAZE has added a link in the comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030183/insert-data-into-sql-server-from-c-sharp-code) which should point you in the right direction.

Comment: It was very helpful!i didnt know that datetime is need to be enclosed with quotes are there more types who need to be enclosed?i only familier that string needs quotes + datetime(from here ;] )

Answer (score 1):

> you can also create a method call it and do something like this.
>   This would require that you create a stored procedure with the @Parameters shown in this example ** if this is Access then petelids Answer will be a great starting point if this is SQL Server then what I have posted would work for you

```
private void InsertMyData(string UserId, DateTime DayMonthYear, double Price, string Address)
{ 
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Order] ([UserID],[DayMonthYear],[PriceToPay],[StatusID],[AdressToSend]) 
                                         VALUES (@UserId, @DayMonthYear, @Price, 1, @Address)";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", UserId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DayMonthYear", DayMonthYear);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PriceToPay", Price);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusID", 1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdressToSend", Adress);
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```